# Restlet ClientResource Post Chunked Encoding - WCF Unsuported

Tags: java, .net, wcf, rest, restlet

I'm developing a product that will use extensively of Restlet for consume
WCF Rest Services. I had created a method to post a XML of a class
containing 2 attributes.

Restlet post my xml with Transfer-Encoding: chunked, and my WCF service,
can't to interpret posted content, unfortunately WCF continues can't to
deserialize my class parameters.

I tried to use the solution described here: 
http://osdir.com/ml/java.restlet/2007-05/msg00097.html
but it won't work for me. My restlet client continues to post my request content using
Transfer-Encoding: chunked. =(

Anybody had a problem like this? Can anybody help-me???

Thanks all and sorry by bad bad english =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you contact Restlet community directly:
http://www.restlet.org/community/lists

Try to provide sample code reproducing the issue.

Best regards,

### Jerome Louvel

Restlet ~ Founder and Lead developer ~ http://www.restlet.org
Noelios Technologies ~ Co-founder ~ http://www.noelios.com